# A simple program in C, need some input

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple program where it ask user to enter a bunch of positive integers, and calculate the average of all the number entered. Program will terminate when user enter a non positive number like 0 or -1.

Here is my code. For some reason I get an error right when I try to enter the first input, can someone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int input=0, sum=0,average=0,i=0;

  printf("Please enter positive numbers, enter 0 or -1 to end:\n");

  scanf("%d",input);

  while (input>0) 
  {
    sum+=input;
    i++;
    scanf("%d",input);
  }
  average=sum/i;
  printf("The average is %d",average);
}
```

Comment: FYI, 0 is a positive integer too.

Comment: @jer *[In mathematics, every real number other than zero is either positive or negative.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number)*

Comment: Please don't ever say "I get an error" without describing the error message, how and when it occurred.  All errors are not equivalent or interchangable.

Comment: @cnicutar In C, 0 is positive. :)

Comment: @jer Says who ? :-) The standard speaks of positive zero and negative zero for certain representations.

Comment: @cnicutar My apologies, just went looking in the standard, noted that INT_MIN/INT_MAX are defined as having the same range, irrespective of the sign/padding bits. As such, whereas on my platform, a sign extended 0 is actually a whole other number, C99 doesn't mandate that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass **the address of the variable** to `scanf`.Try this:

```
scanf("%d", &input);
            ^
```

Also see the [C FAQ: Why doesn't the call `scanf("%d", i)` work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html)

Comment: @Tuan Happens to the best of us.